# Yet another constant associated to regular polygons!

Tags: geometry, reference-request

Consider any regular polygon and an arbitrary circle with center at the centroid of the polygon. Let $L$ be an arbitrary line tangent to the circle. Then, the sum of the distances from the vertices of the polygon to $L$ is constant.

Any reference for this problem?

EDIT: I have found an extension of this result for a tetrahedron. Consider a tetrahedron ABCD and its circumsphere. Let $P$ be a plane tangent to the circumsphere. Then, the sum of the distances from the vertices of the tetrahedron to the plane $P$ is constant. I suspect this is true for any sphere with center at the centroid of the tetrahedron ABCD. Does it generalize to other regular polyhedra?

Comment: What are you looking for exactly?  A citable reference that discusses this?  A proof?  A reference that puts it in some sort of context?

Comment: Found this playing with GeoGebra and I am looking for a citable reference.

Comment: This is only true if the circle is big enough that the polygon lies entirely inside it.

Comment: @Rahul, in the other case one probably has to take signs into account.

Comment: @Mariano: Yes, taking the sum of signed distances (with respect to the center of the circle) will do it.

Comment: @JeanMarie, your reference is for the sum of the *squares* of the distances.

Comment: I beg your pardon. Very sorry for that. I have been abused by the title "Distances to a line from vertices of a regular polygon"

Comment: Here is, at last, a convenient reference : Theorem p. 73 of "Advanced Euclidean Geometry" by Roger A. Johnson" (that can be seen as a google book)

Comment: (Ctd) and you can see on this page two theorems, the second one being for the case $R<1$ (my notations) where there is indeed a need for signed distances as remarked by @Rahul and Mariano.

Comment: In fact, the first reference I gave (https://ckrao.wordpress.com/2015/04/19/distances-to-a-line-from-vertices-of-a-regular-polygon/) was a good one: you only  need to go to the second part of this page '"This enables us to generalise the above result to the following etc." to see that the author generalizes his result to any power of the distances ; taking power 1 gives the result...

Comment: @JeanMarie, thank you!

Comment: I have edited it since I have found a 3d generalization.

Comment: For a set of points $v_1,\ldots,v_n$, let $c=(v_1+\cdots+v_n)/n$ be their centroid, and choose any radius $r\ge\max(\|v_1-c\|,\ldots,\|v_n-c\|)$, so the sphere centered at $c$ with radius $r$ contains all the points. Then for any plane tangent to this sphere, the sum of distances from $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ to the plane is $nr$. This works for all polygons, polyhedra, etc. in any number of dimensions.

Comment: @Rahul, ...all polygons, polyhedra, etc.? There is no need to be regular?

Comment: Yes, this follows from a simple fact: If $n$ points lie on the same side of a plane, their average distance from the plane is equal to the distance of their centroid from the plane. (This is easiest to see if you choose a coordinate system with origin on the plane and $x$-axis along its normal.)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the proof of this property in a certain category of cases.

Let us take as unity the radius of the circumscribed circle to the polygon.

Let $R$ be the radius of the "arbitrary" circle.

We assume that

$$\tag{0} R \geq 1.$$

Let $O$ be the common center to the 2 circles, $N$ the number of sides of the regular polygon.

Let $V_k$ be the name of the $k$th vertex ($k=0,1 \cdots N-1$).

A classical result that we will use later on is :

$$\tag{1}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\vec{OV_K}=0.$$

Let $\theta$ be the polar angle of a normal vector to the tangent line. Thus the rotation by $-\omega$

- turns this tangent line into the tangent line at $A(R,0)$.
- brings points $V_k$ onto points $V'_k$.

Let $W_k$ be the projection of $V'_k$ on the $x$ axis.

We have to compute $\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}length([AW_k])$

These lengths can be computed by taking abscissa $R$ of $A$ minus abscissa of $W_k$ without need for taking signs because the abscissa $R$ of $A$ is bigger that the abscissas of all $W_k$s that are $\leq 1$ due to assumption $(0)$.

Using a complex number representation where

- $V_k$ is associated with $e^{2i \pi k/N}$,
- rotation by $-\omega$ with multiplication by $e^{-i \omega}$,
- projection onto the $x$ axis being realized by taking the real part $\Re$,

we have to show that the following sum is a constant:

$$\tag{2}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\Re(R-e^{2i \pi k/N}e^{-i\omega})=constant.$$

Expanding and grouping:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}(R)-\Re\left(e^{-i\omega}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}e^{2i \pi k/N}\right)=constant$$

But the last sum is zero because of $(1)$.

Thus, it is true that the LHS is equal to a constant, which is NR, being understood that this proof is under condition (0).